# AES256 in java error

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

i am testing AES 256 in a java applet. It works just fine if i decode the byte[] i get in the code. I print the byte in binary format in encoded string textbox. if i take that string and decode, I get an exception `Given final block not properly padded` . What's the problem?

my code follows

---

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet {
 Label lblKey = new Label("Key");
 TextField inputLineKey = new TextField(15);
 Label lblString = new Label("Value");
 TextField inputLineString = new TextField(15);
 Label lblStringEncoded = new Label("Encoded Value");
 TextField inputLineStringEncoded = new TextField(15);
 Label lblStringDecoded = new Label("Decoded Value");
 TextField inputLineStringDecoded = new TextField(15);
 Button encodeButton = new Button("Test Encrypt");
 Button decodeButton = new Button("Test Decrypt");

 public TestApplet() {
  add(inputLineKey);
  add(lblKey);
  add(inputLineString);
  add(lblString);
  add(inputLineStringEncoded);
  add(lblStringEncoded);
  add(inputLineStringDecoded);
  add(lblStringDecoded);
  add(encodeButton);
  add(decodeButton);
  // inputLine.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
 }

 /**
  * Turns array of bytes into string
  * 
  * @param buf
  *            Array of bytes to convert to hex string
  * @return Generated hex string
  */
 public static String asHex(byte buf[]) {
  StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
   if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
    strbuf.append("0");

   strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
  }

  return strbuf.toString();
 }

 public boolean action(Event e, Object args) {

  // so do something!

  // ///////////////////////
  try {
   String message = "This is just an example";

   // Get the KeyGenerator

   KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
   kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available

   // Generate the secret key specs.
   SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
   byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

   SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

   // Instantiate the cipher

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

   if (e.target == encodeButton) { // User has clicked on encrypt
           // button
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal((inputLineString.getText()
      .length() == 0 ? message : inputLineString.getText())
      .getBytes());
    // System.out.println("encrypted string: " + asHex(encrypted));

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    String originalString = new String(original);
    // System.out.println("Original string: " +
    // originalString + " " + asHex(original));

    // Create a BigInteger using the byte array
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(encrypted);

    inputLineStringEncoded.setText(bi.toString(2)); // (new String(encrypted));
    inputLineStringDecoded.setText(originalString);
   }

   if (e.target == decodeButton) { // User has clicked on decrypt
           // button
   // cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
   //
   // byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal((inputLineString.getText()
   // .length() == 0 ? message : inputLineString.getText())
   // .getBytes());
   // // System.out.println("encrypted string: " + asHex(encrypted));

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    // Parse binary string
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(inputLineStringEncoded
      .getText(), 2);

    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(bi.toByteArray());
    String originalString = new String(original);
    // System.out.println("Original string: " +
    // originalString + " " + asHex(original));
    inputLineString.setText(originalString);
    inputLineStringDecoded.setText(originalString);
   }

  } catch (Exception exc) {
   inputLineStringEncoded.setText(exc.getMessage());
  }
  return true; // Yes, we do need this!
 }

 class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  }
 }
}
________________________________
```

Comment: have you tried passing the byte array that you get after encrypting directly to your decrypt routine? Maybe you are loosing something along the way going via a BigDecimal and a String representation of the binary...

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
String originalString = new String(original);
```

You're taking opaque binary data and trying to interpret it as if it were a valid text string. It almost certainly won't be. Furthermore, you're converting it using the system default encoding, which is almost *never* a good idea.

To represent arbitrary binary data in text, it's best to use base64 to encode and decode it. Alternatively, use hex - you've already got a way of converting binary data to hex, so you might want to use that. It's slightly longer than base64, but you may find it easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You should encode `byte[] encrypted` in some suitable TEXT format like hex encode or base64. To decrypt you pass from text representation again to `byte[]`.

The problem is around these lines:

```
byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(bi.toByteArray());
String originalString = new String(original);
```

and

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(encrypted);
```

Where you must encode it to a string using, for example, one of the above encodings. Take a look at commons-codec for that task.

http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html